# Would there be a security issue if expose the wallet address?

Tags: solidity

I am developing a smart contract and exposing my wallet address as a receiver of the cryptocurrency of a certain function of selling NFT. I wonder if there would be a security issue, as I have seen some articles that hackers may send modified NFT or crypto to hack your wallet.

If there will be a security issue, would there be a better way to set the receiver address? I also heard that the `owner` of a smart contract could potentially be hacked by hackers as well so I am not sure if that would be a more secure option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each account has a `public key` and a `private key`. Only the private key should  NOT be exposed to anyone because it is used to hash transaction. When known, others could send transactions on your behalf.

Receiving a modified NFT which leads to hack is not considered a smart-contract flaw.